# Are there numbers on how many pre-orders (or total GH/s) ButterflyLabs already received?

Tags: asic, difficulty, hashpower, mining-hardware, butterfly-labs

The whole Bitcoin world is waiting for ButterflyLabs' entree in the mining scene.

Their promised products are quite revolutionary and so they can cause great fluctuations in the BTC price when they finally arrive.

To know how the Bitcoin network would be affected, it would be very useful and interesting to have an idea on how much hashpower will enter for mining.

Calculations of the profits from their miners with the current difficulty are absurd (like a $ 1,299 miner being paid back in just 4 days) and make no sense.
When making estimates for your profit you need also to consider changes in the difficulty, which are predicted to be enormous when ButterflyLabs' hardware launches.

So, to come to my question, I know that Butterfly Labs is not the most transparent company and that they failed to keep most of their promises. But did they ever mentioned numbers or approximations of how many pre-orders they already received? Or how much hashpower they would account for?

Answer (score 1):

I found this :

[BFL SC Pre-Order Information](http://bfl.ptz.ro/)

So. 6000 units ordered from june 2012 to june 2013. 100 were shipped, in june 2013. 5900 to go.

Comment: The link doesn't include shipped total, are we supposed to manually count the green lines? O_o

Comment: That's the best you're gonna find. Steven/user5560 did a good job... Yes you could count the green lines like everyone else, or make yourself a script... but BFL does not announce total orders and the likes. It is all hearsay beyond what they tell you(which is nothing)